# Docker NameError: name 'app' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to make a Flask framework with python and trying to host it on Docker.

```
#importing dependencies
from flask import Flask

#initializing the name of the application
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def hello(parameter_list):
    return 'Hello, this is my first try on Docker'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug= True)
```

I am getting at Line 5 that ***name 'app' is not defined***

[image: NameError] 
what should i do to remove this error?
this is my first time asking a question over here, Please let me know if any other clarification is needed or suggestions for future posts.
Thanks in advance

Comment: you can copy the traceback on the question instead of using picture. Doing so will help a lot to people who want to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

The error you have shown in the image and the code does not seem matched. to reproduce your error is to pass `app` to flask object instead of `__name__`.

[image]

Here you go with HelloWorld

```
FROM python:alpine3.7
RUN pip install flask==0.10.1
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
CMD python app.py
```

and `app.py`

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Welcome to the Data Science Learner!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=int("5000"), debug=True)
```

build

```
docker build -t flask-test .
```

run

```
docker run -it --rm flask-test
```

You can use the same with Docker compose,

```
docker-compose rm -f && docker-compose up --build
```

Comment: I had the same issue, I had some error in py file, however after fixing the error and running **docker-compose up** was still not working, however when I ran **docker-compose up --build** worked as it started creating the build from scratch